# change the proxy settings on webkit-sharp for mono

Tags: c#, proxy, mono, webkit, browser

I'm really new to Mono development and have been trying to create a small application (no toolbar, no url entry field) that opens a fixed url and shows the page to the user, I was able to accomplish that by following a few tutorials on the internet (the basic idea I found on this website: http://mapopa.blogspot.com.br/2011/05/webkit-based-webbrowser-written-in-mono_29.html).

Now I'm wondering if is there a way to set the proxy settings for this component (the webview from webkit-sharp), I've been digging around it's API and searching for documentation with no luck so far, any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the managed wrappers don't expose this functionality. Following quick hack should be enough to get you started:

```
public class SoupSession
{
    [DllImport("webkit-1.0")]
    static extern IntPtr webkit_get_default_session();

    [DllImport("soup-2.4")]
    static extern IntPtr soup_uri_new(string uri);

    [DllImport("gobject-2.0")]
    static extern void g_object_set(IntPtr obj, string name, IntPtr value, IntPtr zero);

    public static void SetProxy(string uri)
    {
        IntPtr session = webkit_get_default_session();
        g_object_set(session, "proxy-uri", soup_uri_new(uri), IntPtr.Zero);
    }
}
```

Note that I omitted utf-8 conversions for brevity. You can turn this into a proper wrapper class, if you want.